# What is the best URL Rewriter to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm looking for an URL-rewriter to use in my web-site. Does anybody suggest the best one I should use?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing better than [Scott Guthrie's tips and tricks about Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).
The article suggests some good products to use like :

- [UrlRewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/), open-source.
- [UrlRewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/en/Default.aspx), open-source.
- [Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx), open-source, for IIS 5/6.
- [Helicon Tech's ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), $99, for IIS 5/6.

Comment: Should also try Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy at http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2):

You can try the route engine available in .NET 3.5 SP1. It's used by ASP.NET MVC.

Check out here: [Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx)

The upcoming ASP.NET 4.0 will also bring some better support for routing with WebForms: [ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms Routing – Part I](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/08/09/asp-net-4-0-webforms-routing-part-i/)

Comment: Aggree - Since asp.net has build in routing now, you should use that. I'm using it in a .net 4.0 project, and it works beatifully. An because it's build into the framework, you don't need hacks to get postbacks to work properly.

Comment: Routing is not a URL Rewriter. You can't normalize your domain to www. You can't map legacy urls. Routing is for new .net projects only.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not ask specifically for a module written in managed code nor did you constraint IIS to a specific version, I going to recommend Microsoft's own [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite), a module implemented in native code specific for IIS 7.0

Answer (score 1):

I am really a bit shocked to see people recommending using some 3rd party tool for this, or even buying one!

It's pretty trivial to implement yourself; just make sure IIS maps wild-card requests to ASP.NET, then implement 'BeginRequest' in the global.asax; check for the style of url that's coming in, and then create the 'real' url and use that! Easy, and shouldn't take more than 20 mins to get a simple sample working. Then you can just adjust as needed ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

Managed Fusion URL Rewriter
Seems to be the most updated tool because it says:
Full .NET 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 support.
Full support for IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 (including integrated pipelines).
Many other tools do not play nice with iis7 and do not allow integrated pipelines.
http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/

Scott Guthrie's article, was great when it was written. However it's highly outdated today and I would no longer recommend the tools he suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you need rewriting in IIS, I use Helicon ISAPI ReWrite 3, works really well, cheap license.

Answer (score 0):

I used Helicon too and was satisfied. AFAIR they have a free version that may be sufficient for your needs.